# Number Formatting in excel Vb.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel

Can someone give me some code to set the cell of an excel spreadsheet to a number format that use a max of 2 decimal places. Or would it work better it I change the data I am putting into the cell to a proper format? Here is a sample of data that is going in. Right now its going in as a string...
col("ADJ").ToString() where col is a DataTable oject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure about VB, but in C# it would be:

```
worksheet.Cells["C3"].NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

or

```
worksheet.Cells["A:Z"].NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

or

```
Range.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = """R"" #,##0.00;""R"" -#,##0.00"
```

Another way:

```
worksheet.Cells(x,y).NumberFormat = """R"" #,##0.00;""R"" -#,##0.00"
```

NOTE: this may vary with different versions of Excel.

Comment: I am using the worksheet.Cells(x,y) object can you give me an example with that I do not see it in my intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

In vb.Net:

worksheet.cellRange("X").NumberFormat="#,##0.00"